# Xamarin shared projects - use platform specific services/APIs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

Is it possible to use platform specific code like so:

```
#if __ANDROID__
   using Android.App;
   using Android.Content;
   using Android.Locations;
#endif

public GPSNavigation()
{
     #if __ANDROID__
         manager = (LocationManager)DependencyService.Get<Activity>().GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
         Criteria criteria = new Criteria
                                 {
                                     Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine
                                 };
         IList<string> acceptableLocationProviders = manager.GetProviders(criteria, true);
         if (acceptableLocationProviders.Any())
         {
             locationProvider = acceptableLocationProviders.First();
         }
         else
         {
             locationProvider = "";
         }
     #endif
     #if __IOS__
     #endif
}
```

The code compiles and runs but I get a runtime error of "Unknown identifier: " for all Android specific code such as "Unknown identifier: LocationManager" when executed. Is it not possible to reference platform specific services/APIs within a shared project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in answer to your question, this is possible. Shared projects get whatever references the project that references them have. Otherwise it wouldn't compile. You must have a logic error in your code.

From your code I suspect the value of Context.LocationService is LocationManager and the call to the DependencyService is not resolving it. Why this is occurring is not directly related to using a shared project, but something that needs to be debugged.

Additionally, based on your code you might be able to take advantage of #elif **IOS** instead of the separate #endif and #if **IOS** statements but that is more an organizational preference.